# Uncertainty principle for $\Delta\frac{1}{x}\Delta p$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I've tried to determine uncertainty for operators $\xi=\frac{1}{x}$ and $p$. To do so, I used relation that $B^{-1}[A, B]B^{-1} = -[A, B^{-1}]$ and so I got:
$$
\frac{1}{x}[p, x]\frac{1}{x} = \frac{-i \hbar}{x^2}
$$
which means, the uncertainty is:
$$
\Delta\xi\Delta p \geq \frac{\hbar}{2x^2}
$$
I'm not sure if the uncertainty might be dependent on the x value (for example, uncertainty for operators $x$ and $p$ is greater or equal to $\frac{\hbar}{2}$ which is constant value). Please tell me if my result is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your result is *almost* right, but not quite. Since $x$ is an operator, the right-hand side does not make sense as you've written it, and it needs to be replaced by the expectation value of $\hbar/x^2$.

In that form, it is a special case of the [Robertson uncertainty relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Robertson%E2%80%93Schr%C3%B6dinger_uncertainty_relations),
$$
\sigma _{A}\sigma _{B}\geq{\frac {1}{2}}\left|\langle [{\hat {A}},{\hat {B}}]\rangle \right|
$$
(where the $\langle\cdot\rangle$ represent expectation value, as usual).